# How to run Nuxt (vue js framework) app on aws instance

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am not vue js guy but I am trying to learn and run project on aws.

[image]

I could complete up to this.

I just want to change localhost to my IP address.

I checked few documentation where they referred to change nuxt.config.js but still I could not get where exactly I need to make change.

In Flask If I change host name from localhost to "0.0.0.0" in app.run. It start running on my IP address. Is there any similar concept here?

Any help highly appreciated.

Edit 1

This is how my present code structure
[image]

Comment: My answer was wrong so I delete it.

Comment: Are you trying to `npm run serve` in `EC2` instance?

Comment: Asking about AWS but talking about local environment, I don't get it.